# extracting dates using Regex in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract year from my Data Frame column `data3['CopyRight']`.

```
CopyRight
2015 Sony Music Entertainment
2015 Ultra Records , LLC under exclusive license
2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony Music Entertainment
Compilation ( P ) 2014 Epic Records , a division of Sony Music Entertainment
2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony Music Entertainment
2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony Music Entertainment
```

I am using the below code to extract the year :

```
data3['CopyRight_year'] = data3['CopyRight'].str.extract('([0-9]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
```

with my Code I am only getting the First occurrence of year.

```
CopyRight_year
2015
2015
2014
2014
2014
2014
```

I want to extract all the years mentioned in the column.

Expected Output

```
CopyRight_year
    2015
    2015
    2014,2015
    2014
    2014,2015
    2014,2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with regex for find all integers with length `4` to lists and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) it by separator:

Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew for idea add word boundary `r'\b\d{4}\b'`:

```
data3['CopyRight_year'] = data3['CopyRight'].str.findall(r'\b\d{4}\b').str.join(',')
print (data3)
                                           CopyRight CopyRight_year
0                      2015 Sony Music Entertainment           2015
1   2015 Ultra Records , LLC under exclusive license           2015
2  2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony ...      2014,2015
3  Compilation ( P ) 2014 Epic Records , a divisi...           2014
4  2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony ...      2014,2015
5  2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony ...      2014,2015
```

Comment: I would use `r'\b\d{4}\b'`, since `'(\d{4})'` will match 4-digit chunks even inside longer digit chunks (e.g. `0067` in `006789`).

Comment: @jezrael - Thanks a lot I am getting the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex will just capture the digit, and if you want to capture the comma separated years, then you will need to enhance your regex to this,

```
[0-9]+(?:\s+,\s+[0-9]+)*
```

This regex `[0-9]+` will match the numbers and additionally `(?:\s+,\s+[0-9]+)*` regex will match one or more whitespace followed by a comma and again followed by one or more whitespace and then finally a number and whole of it zero or more times as available in the data.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vhbZHj/1)**

Change your panda dataframe line to this,

```
data3['CopyRight_year'] = data3['CopyRight'].str.extract('([0-9]+(?:\s+,\s+[0-9]+)*)', expand=False).str.replace('\s+','')
```

Prints,

```
                                           CopyRight CopyRight_year
0                      2015 Sony Music Entertainment           2015
1   2015 Ultra Records , LLC under exclusive license           2015
2  2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a 1999 division of ...      2014,2015
3  Compilation ( P ) 2014 Epic Records , a divisi...           2014
4  2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony ...      2014,2015
5  2014 , 2015 Epic Records , a division of Sony ...      2014,2015
```

Although I liked `jezrael` answer which uses `findall` and `join` which gives you more flexibility and cleaner approach.